# Drupal 7 single sign on (w/ Moodle, wiki, etc)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, single-sign-on, moodle

All my users are stored in my drupal 7 user table.

I also have some external sites like a Wiki and Moodle.

I used a single sign on with Drupal-6 and Moodle. Moodle supported users from other systems.

Passwords are not the same when I hash a password in Moodle with the Drupal 7 function `user_hash_password`. There is a new hash each time.

Is there any thing else i need to do with the password in the Drupal 7 user table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Drupal 7 module with a menu hook. The menu hook should accept a username and password as $_POST variables then follow the authentication track of [user_login()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login/7).

So essentially you'd end up with:

```
function my_module_authentication_menu_hook() {
  // Note anywhere below that I put return FALSE you should return a failed auth response.
  // Where there is a return TRUE you should return a successful auth response.
  // The formatting of the auth response is up to you with how your Moodle call will react.
  if (!isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['password'])) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  // Functionality from user_login_name_validate().
  if (user_is_blocked($username)) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  // Functionality from user_login_authenticate_validate().
  // You should add flood handling in here as well, but it can not be IP based, unless you
  // supply the IP of the user through your Moodle functionality.
  if (user_authenticate($username, $password) === FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  // See user_login_final_validate() and implement failed login functionality before success.
  return TRUE;
}
```

Another option, which I can not in good conscience recommend, is if you do not wish to route through Drupal and wish to query the database directly. You will have to reproduce the code of user_check_password() along with it's dependent code _password_crypt(), _password_get_count_log2(), _password_base64_encode() etc. You'll also need to reproduce functionality to identify if the user is blocked or unauthenticated. You will also need to verify that the user is allowed to login with a reproduction of user_login_default_validators() functionality. Then if any of that code updates in Drupal core you'll need to update again. I really recommend routing through Drupal for maintenance reasons.

Comment: As a note, this will accomplish shared sign on, which is not the same as single sign on. Your post was tagged with single sign on but your questions was regarding shared sign on.

If you wish to accomplish a true single sign on there is a lot more required such as shared cookies, configuring session timeout, and a load of other complications that would be very specific to your environment(s).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a module such as the CAS module to drive the password entry to a single site.  Moodle and some wikis support this IIRC.   Use your normal strategy to get the other fields syncronized between products.